# Is there a better way via multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

1. I am using python multiprocessing to process files. Last processed
   file record is stored in a dict A i.e. `dict_A = {'file1_xx': '8-04-22', 'file2_xx': '8-04-22', 'file3_xx': '8-04-22', 'file4_xx': '8-04-22'}`
2. Files directory is scanned, filenames with last modified date are stored in `dict_test`. Files recorded in both dicts are compared for new files: i.e. compare each file last modified date i.e `file1_xx` against the last processed date in `dict_A`. There's a condition which will update the `dict_A` if the file last modified date is greater than last processed date per single file.
3. I am facing issues as the dictionary is not updated after the files are processed.
4. Ideally the `dict_A` should be updated with the latest modified date per file of same category. This `dict_A` is then uploaded to PostgreSQL db through sqlalchemy.

```py
def compare_rec(i):
    a = dict_A[i]
    b = dict_test[i]
    if a >= b:
        print("none")
    else:
        lock.acquire()
        print("found")
        a = b
        lock.release()

def init(l):
    global lock
    lock = l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_cat=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    dict_A={'a': '10', 'b': '10', 'c': '10', 'd': '10'}
    dict_test={'a': '11', 'b': '11', 'c': '11', 'd': '11'}
    l = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(l,))
    pool.map(compare_rec, file_cat)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Yes, not using multiprocessing. Just write a loop.

Comment: Processes run in separate memory-spaces, so global variables aren't shared.

Comment: processes should return result of compariton and main process should update `dict_A` (when it gets all results)

Comment: @furas Can u please give me a code example? I tried having a separate variable per process but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes don't share variables.

In function I would use `return` to send `filename` and `date`  back to main process

```
if ...:
    return i, a  
else:
    return i, b
```

main thread should get results from all processes

```
results = pool.map(compare_rec, file_cat)
```

and it should update dictonary

```
dict_A.update(results)
```

---

Full code:

```
import multiprocessing

def compare_rec(key):
    print('key:', key)
    
    a = dict_A[key]
    b = dict_test[key]
    
    if a >= b:
        print("none", key, a)
        return key, a   
    else:
        print("found:", key, b)
        return key, b
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    file_cat  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    dict_A    = {'a': '10', 'b': '10', 'c': '10', 'd': '10'}
    dict_test = {'a': '11', 'b': '11', 'c': '11', 'd': '11'}

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    
    results = pool.map(compare_rec, file_cat)
    print(results)
    
    print('before:', dict_A)
    dict_A.update(results)
    print('after :', dict_A)
    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: I am getting "dict_A is not defined error". Do u think both dictionaries should be global variable or should be passed as arguments to `pool.map(compare_rec, file_cat)` ? if it's the later can u plz give me a code example? what do u think about `pool.starmap()`? Appreciate ur help

Comment: Added partial function to ur code, works fine now.

Comment: frankly I would create list with tuples `[("a", 10 , 11), ("b", 10, 11), ...]` - so every process would get directly three values `("a", 10 , 11)` without using `dict_A` `dict_test`.

Comment: My case is different, dict_A is fixed updated with last modified date per keys, i.e 'a' while dict_test is varying, each dict_test.keys() has multiple values.

Comment: as for me it doesn't matter what you have in dictionares - you can send directly tuple `("a", dict_A["a"], dict_test["a"])` without sending full `dict_A`, `dict_test`.

Comment: Actually that's what I'm doing in my main code `result=compare_rec('a', dict_A, dict_test["a"])`, except I was sending full dict_A due to it smaller length which is 27. But I will try with `dict_A["a"]`, that's a good tip.

Comment: By the way in the original code using ur technique for multiprocessing my output of the results is: `results = [[None], [], [('1002', '2022-04-07'), ('1002', '2022-04-07'), ('1002', '2022-04-07'), ('1002', '2022-04-07'), ('1002', '2022-04-07')], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [('1016', '2022-04-07'), ('1016', '2022-04-07')]]`. in this list '1002' is the ''a'' and the date is file modified date. the value of a is range (1001 1026). My desired output would be to remove the None, ' ', and only one value per "a" i.e. a =range(10011026),  Do u mind if u got a better idea cheers.

Comment: it strange that you get back `None` or empty string and you get repeated results - it looks like every process test all values on list but it should test only one value. And it would be simpler if it would return value even if it doesn't have to change it - every `return` should send back the same structure but it seems in some places it return default `None`.